# How to upload files to anonfile api android studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, file-upload

I am trying to make an app and be able to upload files to anonfiles through their api. But i really don't know how because i have never used this type of api.

Request example

```
curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload
```

I tried this in a webview and it works but i want to make able to upload without webview

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://api.anonfiles.com/v1/upload" method="POST"> 
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" /> 
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array --> 
    Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Are you still searching for a solution? If yes, I have one

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you would need to do in Android just to be aloud to do it. First, you would need to get permission to contact the internet, the storage on the device. Here is a great tutorial on how to do what you want to get done.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3hdVJ9aCWs